# How to run GNU-Prolog on VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnu-prolog

I'm new to using VSCode and also I'm learning Prolog so I want to know how to run it from the editor.

I'm on windows and I already activated the enviroment variable `LINEDIT=gui=no`  so when I call `C:\GNU-Prolog\bin\gprolog.exe` it runs on the shell.

to open a file you have to run in the prolog terminal:
`changedirectory(DirectoryPathName).` to go to the file's directory and
`[file]` to open it.

I don't know how to translate that into the VSC settings so I can use it to run Prolog.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Something like defining a task in your tasks.json file. For version 1.5.0 of VSC:

```
{
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "my echo test",
        "command": "echo", // Could be any other cmd
        "args": ["test"],
        "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```